# How to automatically go through and edit long txt files?

Tags: list

I have an issue: I've got some chat logs that are thousands of lines ong, and I'm trying to isolate the messages from one specific user. The log looks like this:

```
[dd-mm-yy hh:mm pm/am] Username
message


[dd-mm-yy hh:mm pm/am] Username
message


[dd-mm-yy hh:mm pm/am] Username
message
```

In my file, I want to only keep the messages (not the other information like day hour or their username) that one specific user has send, and delete everything else, so I can process the contents of those messages. Is there anything out there that can help me achieve it, because as you can see its a very tedious process to go through thousands of lines of logs doing this by hand.

Comment: Can messages contain line breaks?

Comment: if you mean if there could be `\n`, no. If you mean if I mind there being that line break, no I dont. @Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a js script to do what I wanted since I couldnt find anything anywhere else, here it is:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");

async function processLineByLine() {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream("./input.txt");

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity,
    });
    // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
    // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.

    let trigger = false;

    for await (const line of rl) {
        // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
        console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
        if (line.includes("YOU DID THIS TO MY BOI LIM#7483") == true) {
            console.log("true");
            trigger = true;
        }
        else if (trigger == true) {
            console.log(`Line sent by user: ${line}`);

            fs.appendFile("output.txt", line + " ", (err) => {
                // throws an error, you could also catch it here
                if (err) throw err;

                // success case, the file was saved
                console.log("line saved");
            });

            trigger = false;
        }
    }
}

processLineByLine();
```